# How to resize legend element in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to plot covid death numbers in all of the 30 states and union territories. The plot looks like this.[covid_deaths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2HkW.png).
[image]

I want to split the legend in two columns or to resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
plt.legend(fontsize='14', ncol=2)
```

Also it might be a good idea to move the legend outside the plot, which can be done by adding two more arguments.

```
plt.legend(fontsize='14', ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
```